# Can I associate Static IP to my AWS Classic Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have configured classic load balancer for my application and provided dns URL for it to the customer for integration.
Now i want to migrate to Application load balancer but that will lead to change in DNS url for my customer.
So if I get a static IP , i can associate it to my CLB now , as customers to migrate to that IP and then associate the IP to ALB.
is there any way it can be handled better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, only Network Load Balancers offer the option of a static IP. You should probably be setting up your own DNS name that points to the load balancer, and giving that to your customer. Then if your load balancer's DNS were to ever change you would only need to update your own DNS record.